# UITableViewController ; UiTable cell under top bar

Tags: objective-c, uitableview

I'm currently learning Objective-C. I'm currently working on a checklist, but there's a problem, the highest cell, needs to be under the top bar, but instead it is this:

[image]

How can it be solved, that the highest cell is 100% under the top bar?

Thanks!

Comment: move the frame of the tableview down by 20 pixels?

Answer (score 1):

In order to fix this, put this line into your `viewDidLoad` method.

```
self.automaticallyAdjustsScrollViewInsets = YES;
```

The reason for this is that by default in iOS 7, view controllers have a full screen layout which extends to the edges of the screen. When using scroll views, you will want to adjust the content inset of your scroll view to account for this. The property above is a built-in way for that to be done automatically for you when possible.

[See documentation here](https://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/UserExperience/Conceptual/TransitionGuide/AppearanceCustomization.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/TP40013174-CH15-SW1).